# How to use context react correctly?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

There is a  [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-payne-xwfzn?file=/src/index.js)

correct import `import App from './components/app/app'` (imports are not always saved)

Context

```
import React from 'react'
export const DataContext = React.createContext({})
```

App component

```
import { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react'
import Products from '../products/products'
import { DataContext } from '../../services/appContext.js';


const App = () => {
  const { data, setData } = useContext(DataContext)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false)

  const getData = () => {
    setLoading(true)

    fetch('../../services/data.json')
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {          
          return response.json()
        } else {
          throw new Error('Something went wrong')
        }
      })
      .then((json) => {
        setData(json.data)        
        
        setLoaded(true)
        setLoading(false)        
      })
      .catch(() => {        
        setHasError(true)
        setLoaded(false)
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false)
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {hasError && !loading && !loaded && (<div>Error</div>)}
        {loading && !hasError && !loaded && (<div>Loading</div>)}
        {loaded && !hasError && !loading && (
          <DataContext.Provider value={{ data, setData }}>
              <Products />
          </DataContext.Provider>
        )}
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I'm trying to display products using context, but alas, it doesn't work right now.

Explain what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to access `DataContext` with `useContext(DataContext)` before the provider `<DataContext.Provider value={{ data, setData }}>`. Why is that? Is this component also rendered with DataContext.Provider?
`

Comment: Your fetch call to the local JSON is returning an HTML response, hence the call 'response.json()' is failing and you are seeing an 'Error'

Comment: @Sinan Yaman  most likely I misunderstood how context works. Tell me how to use it correctly?

Comment: @random_user yes i get the answer in the catch

Comment: [This article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usecontext-hook) helped me to understand how to use them correctly

Comment: @Dmitriy that's the only issue I see in the code, you are using the context correctly. the fetch path is wrong because, in the built files, the JSON path will change. Either you have to tell webpack to add the JSON to the final build assets, or you can directly import the JSON in your code.

Comment: You can't access the context with `useContext` unless the component is a child of context provider @random_user

Comment: The component Products is indeed a child of the DataContext Provider, so I see no issues there. Can you check again @SinanYaman

Comment: Yes, Products is a child of DataContext Provider, but the App component in the question isn't. And we are trying to access DataContext with `useContext`

Comment: Hey, my bad. I did not see that. Yeah, the context is not supposed to be accessed in the App component since it's not a child of the DataConext.Provider. Thanks for that @SinanYaman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple of things going wrong in your code. I have forked your sandbox and edited the code to correct them.

1. JSON path in fetch, the path will change wrt to the bundled JS file. So, instead, you can consider importing it and webpack will take care of importing it rightly.
2. You are passing 'data' as prop to Product Component and trying to access the data using context in Product.

Please check the corrected and working code, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-maxwell-zi1u5)